# OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() does not save changes in ms access database

Tags: c#, .net

I have `.mdb` database, and code like this:

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE myTab SET col2 = @val1 WHERE col1 = @val2";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", 0);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", -1);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
     }
}
```

I get data from db, change it in my gui programm, then save it in db. Changes saves, but not  in db (I don't know where), so when I run program, change data, close program, then again run - changes remain, but when I open db (not in programm), there are no changes saved, and again run - all changes disappear.
PS: when I commit changes, then run program several times, all changes disappear too, after (3-4 runs)

Comment: are you sure .mdb file don't replace in debug folder?(when run application)

Comment: Could you show your connectionString? In particular, Where is located the database you are trying to open?

Comment: @hamidrezamansouri - you could post that as an answer. It's a multiple dupe but too much trouble to look up.

Comment: @ hamid reza mansouri, actually it is, in debug folder there is changed db, so as I uderstood, it saves all changes in that folder, but get all data from another `connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source = Resources\\myDataBase.mdb"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we we add `.mdb` in project root in VS ,when change structure ,VS default delete `.mdb` file in debug folder and replace new file; now you can change this defult :

1- right click `.mdb` file and select option

2- set `Copy To Output Directory` to `Do Not Copy`

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely the WHERE clause of your update statement isn't locating any records to update.

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/10/16/why-sql-updates-fail-three-reasons.aspx

Comment: _"then again run - changes remain"_ = so the WHERE seems OK.