# C# MS Access oledbcommand.executeNonQuery UPDATE no error, no change

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledbcommand

Im trying to use the following script to Update values in an MS Access database.

I have verified that the generated query is valid and that it works if I input it inside MS Access.

Also I verified that oledbcommand.executeNonQuery() returns the correct number of rows that should be modified.

And finally, I am receiving no errors as far as I know.

However when I check the database after I run the code there are no changes. Does Anyone have any insight on why this might be?

I have other functions that retrieve data from the database that work fine using oledbcommand. However i cant get it to modify the database.

Please not that Im aware that this script doesnt protect against injection, but that is outside the scope of this question. Im simply just trying to learn how to update the database.

```
void IDatabase.UpdateRecordValue(string table, string updateColumn, string updateValue, string lookUpColumn, string lookUpValue)
{
       connection.Open();
       OleDbCommand cmdUpdate = new OleDbCommand();

       string sqlQuery = "UPDATE [" + table + "] " +
                         "SET [" + table + "].[" + updateColumn + "] = '" + updateValue + "' " +
                         "WHERE [" + table + "].[" + lookUpColumn + "] = '" + lookUpValue + "';";

       cmdUpdate.CommandText = sqlQuery;
       cmdUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmdUpdate.Connection = connection;

       cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
       connection.Close();
}
```

**EDIT:** my connection string is as follows, there is no password on the database: `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};"`

**EDIT** Here is an actual query example that Im trying to use

```
UPDATE [Rooms] 
SET [Rooms].[Main Space Category] = '5'
WHERE [Rooms].[Number] = '100';
```

Comment: Are your project's settings using the expected db file? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13014788/77335

Comment: Yes Ive verified that as well, other functions that retrieve data from the database pull in the correct data. It just stops working when I try to Update the database

Comment: Is the problem limited to this one `UPDATE`?  Can you alter any data (`INSERT`, `DELETE`) in that db file from c#?

Comment: I havnt written a script for those, I dont need them for this particular project

Comment: Have you verified that the columns specified by `updateColumn` and `lookupColumn` are always going to be of type `Text` (or `Memo`)?

Comment: I do need to validate that sometime in the future, In my test, I know that my database field that I'm writing to is of type "Short Text"

Comment: Also, I should add, since this is a MS Access database, While my program is running Ive noticed that the lock file for the database never shows up. When I run a similar script in VBA when ever it access the database, that lock file always shows up. I dont know if that means anything or not.

Comment: This leaves me uneasy: *"I am receiving no errors **as far as I know.**"*  Eliminate the uncertainty.

Comment: If the lock file does not show up, that means you're not actually connecting to the db file.

Comment: If that is the case then how would it be retrieving data from the same connection? I have functions that utilize the same connection that find table names, find column values, and single values.

Comment: "I am receiving no errors as far as I know." I used that sentence because this is the first time that Im using the OleDb framework. I know how to do traditional error handling but I wanted to leave my self open if someone knew something about OleDb that I didnt.

Comment: You're using OleDb with the Access db engine.  The only possible way for the db engine to connect to a db file *without* creating/updating a lock file is if it connects read-only.  So either you're somehow missing db engine errors when attempting to `UPDATE` on a read-only connection, or you are not connecting to the correct db file.

Comment: That makes sense, I edited my question with my connection string in case that gives anything away. Maby I need to alter it to make it not read only? Also the only way I can tell that will give me any feedback on weather im getting a error or not is the return value of ExecuteNonQuery(). Its returning 1 (1 is that it supposedly altered 1 record)

Comment: `cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();` will return a number for how many records were affected.

Comment: I know, lol, As I stated, Im receiving "1" which is the correct number of records I'm expecting to alter. However, nothing actually gets altered. The database remains unchanged

Comment: I've never done this task before, but your connection string did get my attention, specifically the `{0}` part.  Did you do that to anonymize the location for our sake? According to http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/, that should be the actual filepath to the accdb.

Comment: Yes the string is anonymized, the {0} is properly formatted with the correct path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get no error when your code executes this `UPDATE`, and `cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns 1 as expected.

```
UPDATE [Rooms] 
SET [Rooms].[Main Space Category] = '5'
WHERE [Rooms].[Number] = '100';
```

Yet you report the db does not actually get updated.  Investigate that point further.  Try this `SELECT` from the same OleDB connection object you used when executing the `UPDATE`.

```
SELECT [Rooms].[Main Space Category]
FROM [Rooms]
WHERE [Rooms].[Number] = '100';
```

For extra measure, double-check the Data Source in the connection object's  `ConnectionString` property.

```
Console.WriteLine(connection.ConnectionString)
```

Comment: Well Im stumped...I turned my computer off, took some time off and then got back on just now to hash it out and it works. I dont think I changed anything. Im happy that its working now but it makes me feel uneasy that I dont know why it didnt work before, so I can prevent it in the future. The only thing I can think of is that something was locking the database in read only that didnt reactivate when I restarted my computer. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What did you see from the `SELECT` I suggested --- the old or updated `[Main Space Category]` value?

Comment: It returned the proper value as well

Comment: If proper means the change made with the `UPDATE`, the db connection was not read-only.