# Trouble with UPDATE command c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Ok been starring at this for a good while and i can not under stand why it is not updating my database..... I do not get an error messages it runs just fine. Code below

```
         if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // #WORK
            string searchtext = txtAssetScanned.Text;
            string searchcmd = "UPDATE " + lstCompCode.SelectedItem.ToString() + " SET " + lstCompCode.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".[Inventory Status]= \"FOUND\" WHERE [Inventory number] like '*" + searchtext + "';";
            MessageBox.Show(searchcmd);
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbCommand search = new OleDbCommand();
            search.Connection = myConnection;
            search.CommandText = searchcmd;
            search.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: `[Inventory Status]= \"FOUND\"` should be `[Inventory Status]= 'FOUND'` (Use single-quotes)

Comment: In the `WHERE` clause you have a `LIKE` comparison but the value starts with a `*`. In Microsoft Sql Server wild cards start with `%` symbols, not stars.

Comment: The information you are providing is very minimal. You should at least mention what database you are using (what would allow us to tell if you're `like` condition is correct or not). Have a look at the return value of the `ExecuteNonQuery()` call. What does it return? Is this MS Access?

Comment: I am just using a access datafile for my database

Comment: Also you should be using parameterized sql and not building the parameters into your statement as string literals. This is bad practice as it makes your code vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It can also lead to run time errors in your code if you do not escape string parameters.

Comment: Step through your code in debug. Then make sure that the searchcmd string value is valid. Also, add a Try-Catch block and check to see if an exception is generated during execution.

Comment: single quotes also did not help

Comment: no exceptions are thrown and i have a message box showing the search string so i know that is correct

Comment: To further isolate the problem, you can try 1) running the `update` statement directly in the database to see if it works ok. 2) Convert the `update` statement to a `select` statement to read the results and validate that the predicate is correct.

Comment: When i run the sql in access it updates the table correctly. When i run it in my code it does not update

Comment: Please check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012881/oledbcommand-executenonquery-does-not-save-changes-in-ms-access-database), I think you may be having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that pop out here :

- **Use Parameterized Queries.** You should be using parameterized queries, concatenating in the manner you currently are can cause syntax issues and leave you vulnerable to SQL Injection.
- **Consider Using Single Quotes for Values**. When setting string values in SQL, you should use single quotes `'value'` as opposed to double quotes (i.e. `"value"`).
- **SelectedValue over SelectedItem**. Consider using the `SelectedValue` property as opposed to `SelectedItem.ToString()` to ensure you use the proper value.
- **Table Names as Parameters May Not Be Allowed**. If you are using a table name as a parameter, which in many cases may be flat out rejected (as they are generally reserved for values), so fair warning.
- **Double-check for Typos**. Finally, ensure the properties that you are targeting are correct and do not contain any typos (i.e. `Foo.[Inventory number]`, etc.)

You can apply these changes as follows :

```
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection("{your-connection-string}"))
{
      // Build your query with parameters
      var query = "UPDATE ? SET [Inventory Status] = 'FOUND' WHERE [Inventory number] LIKE ?";
      using(var command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
      {
           connection.Open();
           // Add your parameters
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table",lstCompCode.SelectedValue);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "*" + txtAssetScanned.Text);
           // Now that your queries are added, perform your update
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
}
```

**The Likely Issue**

As I mentioned, some databases will not allow you to pass in table names as parameters without resorting to stored procedures, dynamic SQL, etc. You may be better off simply defining the table that you want to use directly :

```
var query = "UPDATE [YourTableName] SET [Inventory Status] = 'FOUND' WHERE [Inventory number] LIKE ?";
```

Since you cannot pass this through via parameters, you might consider adding some logic to determine which to use and hard-code it along with some sanitation to avoid possible nefarious behavior.

Comment: I removed the concatenation in my example, likely for readability purposes as it should be scoped through the `UPDATE {table}` syntax. I still am not sure if it will even work using that approach though.

Comment: IMO, an answer using `UPDATE ? SET ...` with the caveat "this might not work" is doing a disservice to future readers as it will confuse more than it will help. It certainly won't work with Access SQL.

Comment: That's a fair assessment Gord. I don't believe that it will work either, but god knows with Access. I included it as it was part of OP's original attempt and I've documented further that it is likely the cause of their current issues, at least IMO.